# VB.net - check deep freeze status

Tags: vb.net, deepfreeze

I am running an internet cafe and somebody is unfreezing my deep freeze installed on each pc.

is it possible on vb.net to check deep freeze status?

Thank you!

Comment: What "deep freeze" are you talking about?

Comment: it's faronic's product. when you make changes on your computer, it is deleted when your computer is restarted.

Comment: And you didn't think it was worth mentioning that in your question? I don't think it's something which most developers would have even heard of.

Comment: "Faronics Deep Freeze Enterprise makes PCs indestructible. It protects endpoints by Freezing the desired configuration set by you – the IT professional. Any unwelcome or unwanted changes users make while in-session are prevented from sticking."  It doesn't sound very indestructible if the average user can turn it off!...   =O